# Sample code for progressive video streaming on Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is progressive video streaming in the Android Media Player possible?? if yes then can anyone please provide me with a sample code for the same?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple. You able to use setDataSource method of MediaPlayer or SetPath of VideoView.

Hope it's helpful for you